# Proof of $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

It's a standard result that given $X_1,\cdots ,X_n $ random sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, the random variable $$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}$$ has a chi-square distribution with $(n-1)$ degrees of freedom, where $$S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum^{n}_{i=1}(X_i-\bar{X})^2.$$
I would like help in proving the above result.
Thanks.

Comment: You ought to include your definition of S.

Comment: where $S^2 = \dfrac{\sum_i (X_i - \bar{X})^2}{n-1}$ I assume

Comment: @Emre: I forgot to define it.

Comment: @Henry: Yes, you are right.

Comment: A proof using change of variables can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2953961/321264.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A standard proof goes something like this.  It assumes you already know the following.

1. $\bar{X}$ (the sample mean) and $S^2$ are independent.
2. If $Z \sim N(0,1)$ then $Z^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$.
3. If $X_i \sim \chi^2(1)$ and the $X_i$ are independent then $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \chi^2(n)$.
4. A $\chi^2(n)$ random variable has the moment generating function $(1-2t)^{-n/2}$.

With some algebra, you can show, by adding $-\bar{X} + \bar{X}$ inside the parentheses and grouping appropriately, that $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2 + n(\bar{X} - \mu)^2$.  Then, dividing through by $\sigma^2$ yields
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{X_i - \bar{X}}{\sigma}\right)^2 +  \left(\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)^2.$$
Denote these expressions by $U, V$, and $W$, respectively, so that the formula reads $U = V+W$. 
By facts (2) and (3) above, $U \sim \chi^2(n)$ and $W \sim \chi^2(1)$.  Also, $V = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}$.

Since $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$ are independent, so are $V$ and $W$.  Thus $M_U(t) = M_V(t) M_W(t)$, where $M_X(t)$ denotes the moment generating function of the random variable $X$.  By fact (4) above, this says that $$\frac{1}{(1-2t)^{n/2}} = M_V(t) \frac{1}{(1-2t)^{1/2}}.$$ 
Thus $$M_V(t) = \frac{1}{(1-2t)^{(n-1)/2}},$$ and therefore $V \sim \chi^2(n-1)$.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks Mike:)

Comment: Why does the independence of $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$ imply the independence of $V$ and $W.$ Thanks.

Comment: @Nana: Because $V$ is a function of $S^2$ and $W$ is a function of $\bar{X}$.

Comment: Oh I see...Thanks once again.

Answer (score 22):

I disagree with the characterization of the proof in Mike Spivey's answer as **the** standard proof.  It's the proof for people who don't know about projections in linear algebra.

Notice that the mapping $(X_1,\dots,X_n) \mapsto (X_1-\overline{X},\dots,X_n - \overline{X})$ is a projection onto a space of dimension $n-1$.  Notice also that its expected value is $0$.  Then remember that the probability distribution of the vector $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is spherically symmetric.  Therefore so is the distribution of its projection onto a space of dimension one less.  Hence the square of the norm of that projection is just the square of the norm of a normal random vector with a spherically symmetric distribution centered at the origin.  The square of the norm therefore has a chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the dimension of that space.

Comment: Criticism accepted, and answer upvoted.  I will change the article from definite to indefinite.

Answer (score 10):

Here is another proof. This one doesn't depend on a moment generating functions or linear algebra (explicitly). The essence of the proof is to transform the $(X_i - \overline{X})/\sigma$ variables into $n-1$ independent $N(0,1)$ variables, $Z_i$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \overline{X})^2/\sigma^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}Z_i^2$. I believe that this was the same approach used by Helmert to prove this result  in 1876. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Robert_Helmert.) This proof is long and laborious.

The proof requires the following results:

- If $Y_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_iX_i$ where $X_i \sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ and are the $X_i$ are independent then $Y_i \sim N(\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\mu_i, \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i^2\sigma_i^2)$
- If two Normally distributed variables are uncorrelated then they are independent
- If a set of Normal distributed variables are pair-wise independent then they are mutually independent
- If $U_i \sim N(0, 1)$ and the $U_i$ are independent then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}U_i \sim \chi^2(n)$

Define $U_i = (X_i - \mu)/\sigma$ and note that $E[U_i] = 0$ and $V[U_i]= 1$.

Define

$$Z_i = \sqrt{\frac{n - i}{n - i + 1}}\left(U_i - \frac{1}{n-i}\sum_{k=i+1}^nU_k\right) \text{ for } i=1, 2, ..., n-1$$

So

\begin{alignat*}{6}
Z_1 & = \sqrt\frac{n-1}{n}&\bigg(&U_1 - \frac{1}{n-1}&U_2 - \frac{1}{n-1}U_3 - ... -\frac{1}{n-1}&U_{n-1}&-&\frac{1}{n-1}&U_n\bigg) \\
Z_2 & = \sqrt\frac{n-2}{n-1}&\bigg(&&U_2 - \frac{1}{n-2}U_3 - ... -\frac{1}{n-2}&U_{n-1}&-&\frac{1}{n-2}&U_n\bigg) \\
...\\
Z_{n-1} & = \sqrt\frac{1}{2}&\bigg(&&&U_{n-1}&-&&U_n\bigg)
\end{alignat*}

(I can show an easy way to derive this transformation if requested.)

We'll now show that $Z_i \sim N(0, 1)$ and that the $Z_i$ are independent.

$E[Z_i] = \sqrt{\frac{n - i}{n - i + 1}}\left(E[U_i] - \frac{1}{n-i}\sum_{k=i+1}^nE[U_k]\right) = 0$

\begin{align*}
V[Z_i] & = \frac{n-i}{n-i+1}\left(V[U_i] + \left(\frac{1}{n-i}\right)^2\sum_{k=i+1}^nV[U_j]\right) \\
       & = \frac{n-i}{n-i+1}\left(1 + \left(\frac{1}{n-i}\right)^2(n-i)\right) \\
       & = \frac{n-i}{n-i+1}\left(\frac{n-i+1}{n-i}\right) = 1
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
Cov(Z_i, Z_j) & \text{ for } i < j\\
& = E[Z_i Z_j]\\ 
& = E\left[\sqrt{\frac{n - i}{n - i + 1}}\left(U_i - \frac{1}{n-i}\sum_{k=i+1}^nU_k\right)
\sqrt{\frac{n - j}{n - j + 1}}\left(U_j - \frac{1}{n-j}\sum_{k=j+1}^nU_k\right)\right] \\
& = -\sqrt{\frac{(n - i)(n - j)}{(n - i + 1)(n - j + 1 )}}\left(\frac{1}{n-i}\right)\left(E[U_j^2]-\frac{1}{n-j}\sum_{k=j+1}^nE[U_k^2]\right)\\ 
& \text{Ignoring the cross products of the } X_i \text{ since their expectation is } 0\\
& = -\sqrt{\frac{(n - i)(n - j)}{(n - i + 1)(n - j + 1 )}}\left(\frac{1}{n-i}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n-j}(n-j)\right)\\ & = 0
\end{align*}

Thus the $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ and they are independent. Hence $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Z_i^2 \sim \chi^2(n-1).$

Now we'll prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2/\sigma^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Z_i^2$. First note that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{X_i - \overline{X}}{\sigma}\right)^2 
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma} - \frac{\overline{X} - \mu}{\sigma} \right)^2
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(U_i - \overline{U}\right)^2
$$ So we need only show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(U_i - \overline{U}\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Z_i^2$

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(U_i - \overline{U}\right)^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \left(U_i - \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{n} U_j\right)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{n-1}{n}U_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n U_j\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \left((n-1)U_i - \sum_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n U_j\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \left((n-1)^2U_i^2 - 2(n-1)U_i \sum_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n U_j + (\sum_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n U_j)^2 \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \left((n-1)^2U_i^2 - 2(n-1)U_i \sum_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n U_j + \sum_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n U_j^2 + 2\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\neq i}}^{n-1} \sum_{\substack{k=j+1 \\ k\neq i}}^n U_j U_k \right) 
\end{align*}

What is the coefficient of $U_i$ in the sum above? In the $i$th term it's $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2$ and in the other $n-1$ terms it's $\frac{1}{n^2}$. So in total it's $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2 + (n-1)\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{n-1}{n^2}\left( (n - 1) + 1 \right)= \frac{n-1}{n}.$

What is the coefficent of $U_i U_j \text{ }(i \neq j)$ ? In the $i$th and $j$th term it's $-\frac{2(n-1)}{n^2}$ and in the other $n-2$ terms it's $\frac{2}{n^2}$. So in total it's $-2\frac{2(n-1)}{n^2} + (n - 2) \frac{2}{n^2} = \frac{2}{n^2}(n - 2 - 2n + 2) = -\frac{2}{n}$.

$$\text{Thus }\sum_{i=1}^n (U_i - \overline{U})^2 = \frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n U_i^2 -\frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n U_i U_j $$

Let's consider $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Z_i^2$ now.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Z_i^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{n-i}{n-i+1}}\left(U_i - \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{n} U_j\right)\right)^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{n-i}{n-i+1} \left( U_i^2 - \frac{2}{n-i}U_i\sum_{k=i+1}^nU_k  + \frac{1}{(n-i)^2} \left( \sum_{k=i+1}^nU_k \right)^2 \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{n-i}{n-i+1} \left( U_i^2 - \frac{2}{n-i}U_i\sum_{k=i+1}^nU_k  + \frac{1}{(n-i)^2} \sum_{k=i+1}^nU_k^2 + \frac{2}{(n-i)^2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=i+2}^nU_jU_k \right) 
\end{align*}

The coefficient of $U_1$ in the sum above is $\frac{n-1}{n}$ and the coefficient of $U_1U_j$ $(j > 1)$ it's $\frac{n-1}{n} \frac{-2}{n-1} = \frac{-2}{n}$.

Now consider the coefficient of $U_i$ $(i > 1)$. In the $i$th term, it's $\frac{n-i}{n-i+1}$. It's $\frac{1}{(n-j+1)(n-j)}$ in the $j$th term for $j<i$ and doesn't appear in the terms after the $i$th.

\begin{align*}
\text{In total it's }\\ & \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\frac{1}{(n-j+1)(n-j)} + \frac{n-i}{n-i+1} \\ = & \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\left(\frac{1}{n-j} - \frac{1}{n-j+1}\right) +
 \frac{n-i}{n-i+1} 
\\ = & \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\frac{1}{n-j} - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\frac{1}{n-j+1} + \frac{n-i}{n-i+1}
\\ = & \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\frac{1}{n-j} - \sum_{j=0}^{i-2}\frac{1}{n-j} + \frac{n-i}{n-i+1}
\\ = & \frac{1}{n-i+1} - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{n-i}{n-i+1}
\\ = & \frac{n-1}{n}
\end{align*}

Finally, consider the coefficient of $U_sU_t$ where $1 < s < t < n$. In the $s$th, term it's $\frac{n-s}{n-s+1}\frac{-2}{n-s} = \frac{-2}{n-s+1}.$ In the $j$th term where $j<s$, the coefficient is $\frac{n-j}{n-j+1} \frac{2}{(n-j)^2} = \frac{2}{(n-j)(n-j+1)}.$ $U_sU_t$ doesn't appear in terms after the $s$th.

\begin{align*}
\text{So in total it's }\\ & \sum_{j=1}^{s-1}\frac{2}{(n-j)(n-j+1)} + \frac{-2}{n-s+1} 
\\ = & 2\sum_{j=1}^{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{n-j} - \frac{1}{n-j+1}\right) +
\frac{-2}{n-i+1} 
\\ = & 2\left(\frac{1}{n-s+1} - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{-2}{n-s+1}
\\ = & - \frac{2}{n}
\end{align*}

We have shown
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Z_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}  \frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n U_i^2 -\frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n U_i U_j $$.

Thus $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2/\sigma^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Z_i^2 \sim \chi^2(n-1)$.

Comment: Holy smokes... you are a bold explorer. Thanks for your effort. I see why it's usually proven in textbooks with MGFs or linear algebra.

Comment: The chi-squared formula can be found on page 207 (PDF) or 192 (page number) in https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN599415665_0021. The Helmert document is written in german and is only a photocopy of an original document.

Answer (score 5):

A neat trick is to write $Y_i:=X_i-\mu$. Shifting each of the $X$'s by the same amount doesn't affect the sample variance, so compute the sample variance $S^2$ using the $Y$'s:
$$
(n-1)S^2 =\sum_1^n(Y_i-\bar Y)^2=\sum_1^n(Y_i^2 -2 \bar YY_i + \bar Y^2)=\sum_1^nY_i^2-2\bar Y\sum Y_i+n\bar Y^2=\sum_1^n Y_i^2 -n\bar Y^2
$$
where the last step uses $\sum_1^n Y_i = n\bar Y$. Substituting back $Y_i=X_i-\mu$, this establishes the familiar identity
$$(n-1)S^2
=\sum_1^n(X_i-\mu)^2-n(\bar X-\mu)^2.\tag1
$$
Divide (1) through by $\sigma^2$ and rearrange to the form
$$
\sum_1^n \left[\frac{X_i-\mu}\sigma\right]^2 = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} + \left[\frac{\bar X-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n}\right]^2.\tag2
$$
We recognize that each of the bracketed terms in (2) has a standard normal distribution. In particular the LHS is the sum of squares of $n$ independent standard normals. Compare this observation to the RHS. If you accept that$^{\color{red}a}$ $S^2$ and $\bar X$ are independent, then the RHS is the sum of two independent variables, namely $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ and the square of a single standard normal variable. It must follow that$^{\color{red}b}$ $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ has the same distribution as the sum of squares of $n-1$ standard normals -- so by definition it has chi-squared($n-1$) distribution.

---

$\color{red}a$ You can in fact deduce independence from (2), which shows how the joint density of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ can be factorized into
 a term involving $(X_1-\bar X, X_2-\bar X,\ldots, X_n-\bar X)$ and a term involving $\bar X$. This can be made rigorous with the (linear, invertible) change of variables $(W_1, W_2,\ldots,W_n):=(\bar X, X_2-\bar X,\ldots, X_n-\bar X)$.

$\color{red}b$ This follows from independence and the fact that the moment generating function $E[e^{tU}]$ (alternatively, the characteristic function $E[e^{itU}]$) uniquely defines the distribution of random variable $U$.

Answer (score 2):

The following proof comes from my previous college math instructor. It somewhat wraps up @hwiechers arguments and expands @Michael Hardy's arguments. It is extra long because I try to put all the details for those potential readers who are not familiar with random vectors and matrix algebra, usually most of which are omitted when writing proofs.

---

Consider the random vector $$\mathbf{X}:=[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n]^T,$$ which satisfies $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{X})=\mu\mathbf{e}$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{X})=\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_n$, in which $\mathbf{e}=[1,1,\ldots,1]^T$ is an all-one vector of length $n$ and $\mathbf{I}_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$. Then observe that $$\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{X}$$ and hence

\begin{align*}
\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}&=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i^2}-n\bar{X}^2\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\left[\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}-n\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{X}\right)^2\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\left(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}-\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{e}\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{X}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}, 
\end{align*}
where $$\mathbf{A}:=\mathbf{I}_n-\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{e}\mathbf{e}^T.$$

> **Fact.** The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is real symmetric, hence real orthogonally diagonalizable. In particular, the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ are $1$ of multiplicity $n-1$ and $0$ of multiplicity $1$. We may then let $\mathbf{Q}$ be an $n\times n$ real orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes $\mathbf{A}$. That is, $$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{Q}\begin{bmatrix} 1 &  &  &  & \\  & 1 &  &  &  \\  &  & \ddots &  & \\  &  &  & 1 &  \\  &  &  &  &  0 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{Q}^T=:\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{Q}^T.$$ In addition, if we partition $\mathbf{Q}$ by columns: $$\mathbf{Q}=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{q}_1 & \mathbf{q}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{q}_{n-1} & \mathbf{q}_n \end{bmatrix},$$ then $\mathbf{q}_1,\mathbf{q}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{q}_{n-1}$ is an orthonormal basis of the eigenspace of $\mathbf{A}$ associated with $1$, and $\mathbf{q}_n$ is a unit eigenvector of $\mathbf{A}$ associated with $0$.

Adopting the notations above, we have $$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{X}=:\mathbf{Y}^T\mathbf{D}\mathbf{Y},$$ where $$\mathbf{Y}=[Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n]^T:=\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{X}$$ Based on the structure of $\mathbf{D}$, we can see that $$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}=\mathbf{Y}^T\mathbf{D}\mathbf{Y}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{Y_i^2}.\tag{$*$}$$ **It then suffices to show that $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_{n-1}$ are i.i.d. standard normal r.v.s.**

---

To see this, first observe that
$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{Y})=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{X}\right)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf{Q}^T\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{X})=\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf{Q}^T(\mu\mathbf{e})=\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{e}.$$
Consider now the matrix form $$\mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{e}=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{q}_1^T \\ \mathbf{q}_2^T \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{q}_{n-1}^T \\ \mathbf{q}_n^T \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{e}=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{q}_1^T\mathbf{e} \\ \mathbf{q}_2^T\mathbf{e} \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{q}_{n-1}^T\mathbf{e} \\ \mathbf{q}_n^T\mathbf{e} \end{bmatrix}.$$
Note that for $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$, we have $$\mathbf{q}_i=1\cdot\mathbf{q}_i=\mathbf{Aq}_i=\left(\mathbf{I}_n-\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{e}\mathbf{e}^T\right)\mathbf{q}_i=\mathbf{q}_i-\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{e}\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{q}_i,$$ which implies that $$\mathbf{0}=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{e}\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{q}_i=\frac{\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{q}_i}{n}\mathbf{e}\implies \mathbf{q}_i^T\mathbf{e}=\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{q}_i=0.$$ Thus $$\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{Y})=\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{e}=\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \mathbf{q}_n^T\mathbf{e} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \frac{\mu}{\sigma}\mathbf{q}_n^T\mathbf{e} \end{bmatrix}.$$ That is, $$\mathbb{E}(Y_1)=\mathbb{E}(Y_2)=\cdots=\mathbb{E}(Y_{n-1})=0.\tag{$**$}$$
Note that each $Y_i$ is a linear combination of normal r.v.s, so itself must be a normal r.v. and furthermore their independence is equivalent to zero covariance. Now consider the variance-covariance matrix:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{Y})=\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}\mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{X}\right)=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{Q}^T\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{X})\mathbf{Q}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{Q}^T(\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_n)\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{Q}^T\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{I}_n.
\end{align*}
That is, $$\operatorname{Var}(Y_i)=1~\text{for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$}\quad\text{and}\quad\operatorname{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j)=0~\text{if $i\ne j$}.  \tag{$*$$*$$*$}$$

---

**Additional Question.** What is $\mathbb{E}(Y_n)$?

> Here $\mathbf{q}_n=\mathbf{e}/\sqrt{n}$ whence $\mathbb{E}(Y_n)=\sqrt{n}\mu/\sigma$. But it makes no contributions at all! :)