# How to prove $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi_{n-1}^2$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof of $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \backsim \chi^2_{n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47009/proof-of-fracn-1s2-sigma2-backsim-chi2-n-1)

If $X_1,...,X_n$ is a random sample from a normal distribution and $S^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n-1}$

Could anyone help me show that $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi_{n-1}^2$ and that it's independent to $\bar{X}$

Many thanks!

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68555

Comment: A reference: Section 7.7.2 in Sheldon Ross' *A First Course in Probability*.

Comment: A second reference: Any textbook on the statistical theory of linear regression.

Comment: Thank you for that reference. Ah ok.. it's a duplicate, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X=(X_1,\dots, X_n)^\prime$ has a multivariate
normal distribution with $\mu_X=\mu {\bf 1}$ and $\Sigma_X=\sigma^2 I$.
Here ${\bf 1}$ is the column vector of all $1$s, while $I$ is the
$n\times n$ identity matrix.

Let $A$ be the matrix of an orthogonal transformation
that takes the vector $\bf 1$ into the vector $\sqrt{n}\, {\bf e}_1$.
Then the  vector $U=AX$ is  multivariate
normal with $\mu_U=\mu \sqrt{n}\, {\bf e}_1 $
and $\Sigma_U=\sigma^2 I$.

The first coordinate of the random vector $U$ is
$$U_1=(AX)^\prime{\bf e}_1=X^\prime A^\prime {\bf e}_1=
{1\over \sqrt{n}}\, X^\prime A^\prime A{\bf 1}
= {1\over \sqrt{n}}\, X^\prime {\bf 1}=\sqrt{n}\,\bar X.$$

Also, $$\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i=X^\prime X= X^\prime A^\prime A X=U^\prime U
=n\bar X^2+\sum_{i=2}^n U_i^2,$$
and hence
$${(n-1)S^2 \over \sigma^2} = \sum_{i=2}^n (U_i/\sigma)^2\sim \chi^2_{n-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I assume the end of the last line is a typo?

Comment: @LHS Well, it is my notation for a chi-squared distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. I will change it to match your notation.