# Basic Chi square problem

Tags: statistics, variance

How do I calculate  $P(S^2 > 1.8307(\mathrm{PopVariance}))$ if $n =11$?

I think I should use the Chi square formula:

$$X^2 = \frac{(n-1)s^2}{\mathrm{PopVariance}}$$

But I can't really understand the textbook application of this formula.

Comment: The usual pronunciation is "chi squared" if I understand  your meaning.   See [here for an introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: While we're mentioning English pronunciation, the _ch_ in 'chi' is pronounced like _k_ as in 'Christmas', 'choir', and 'arachnid' (all of Greek origin).

Comment: What is PopVariance ? I don't understand this term ? Can you explain if S2 is equal to SUM(x-xi)2 divided by n or divided by (n-1) ?

Answer (score 1):

If $Q = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1)$ and $n = 11,$ then
you have $$P(S^2 > 1.8397\sigma^2) = P\left(Q=\frac{10S^2}{\sigma^2} > 18.307\right) = 0.05.$$

My computation
below uses R statistical software, but you should be able to
find this result in a printed chi-squared table (row $\nu = 10,$ column
headed .05 for the tail probability).

```
1 - pchisq(18.307, 10)   # in R, 'pchisq' is a CDF
## 0.05000059
```

[image]

Comment: For a proof of the distribution of $Q,$ see [this Q & A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47009/proof-of-fracn-1s2-sigma2-backsim-chi2-n-1).