# Are projections of spherically symmetric distributions always spherically symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry

I originally had this question while I was reading Michael Hardy's high-level proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56744

He states that "the mapping $(X_1,\ldots, X_n) \mapsto (X_1 - \overline{X}, \ldots, X_n - \overline{X})$ is a projection onto a space of dimension $n-1$. Notice also that its expected value is $0$. Then remember that the probability distribution of the vector $(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ is spherically symmetric. Therefore so is the distribution of its projection onto a space of dimension one less."

I tried constructing a rigorous proof of why the statement above about spherical symmetry is true, but my linear algebra/geometry chops are not good enough to get me there. Namely, I assume one should work with a projection matrix, but I'm not sure how to tie in the idea of spherical symmetry.

Can someone help me in thinking about how to prove this?

Comment: I'm fine with downvotes if something wasn't clear, but I'd highly appreciate explanations as to why! That way, I can correct any problems with my question. 

If the downvote was because of a perceived lack of an attempt, I left out work in favor of readability because the work hadn't been fruitful, and at this point, I'm quite stuck and would really appreciate some pointers in the right direction (perhaps I'm mistaken, but that does seem to be the purpose of math.stackexchange in general).

Comment: In summary, meta feedback is very welcome.

Comment: upvoted to cancel the unexplained downvote

Comment: Between commas, `\ldots` looks better than `\cdots`. The latter is for ellipsis between binary operators like $+$. (And perhaps you've noticed that Michael Hardy is pretty much the only one on this site who's more picky about typesetting than I am; I suspect he wouldn't appreciate you misquoting him with a misaligned ellipsis ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @joriki - I had no idea of the difference! I'll make sure to properly quote people in the future too (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any given rotation in an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace can be lifted to a rotation in the $n$-dimensional space by leaving the coordinate orthogonal to it invariant. Rotating the rotationally symmetric distribution in the $n$-dimensional space by the lifted rotation rotates the projected distribution in the $(n-1)$-dimensional space by the given rotation. Since the symmetric distribution doesn’t change, neither does the projected one.