# Sampling Distribution Chi-squard.

Tags: probability-distributions

In the answer to the question I don't understand something, if someone could help me understand.[Proof of $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \backsim \chi^2_{n-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47009/proof-of-fracn-1s2-sigma2-backsim-chi2-n-1) .

Why in the first answer (−/(/√n))^2 does it have distribution 2(1)?

Comment: There is some confusion about this statement. It's better to describe it clearly. But the statement is wrong, since chi-squared distribution is the distribution of $X^2$, where X has the standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_i\sim N(\mu , \sigma^2)$

$\bar{X} \sim N(\mu , \sigma^2/n)$

$\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \sim N(0 , 1)$

$\left(\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\sim \chi^2_{1}$

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!!

Comment: You are welcome.